# How does Foldable.foldl work on Num a => a

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids), there is a piece of code that looks like this.

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)  

instance F.Foldable Tree where  
    foldMap f Empty = mempty  
    foldMap f (Node x l r) = F.foldMap f l `mappend`  
                             f x           `mappend`  
                             F.foldMap f r  

ghci> F.foldl (+) 0 testTree  
42  
ghci> F.foldl (*) 1 testTree  
64800
```

As far as I know, `foldMap` is of type `foldMap :: (Monoid m, Foldable t) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m`, but `Num a => a` itself is not of type `Monoid`, so I am wondering how does `Foldable.foldl` actually work here? And since `foldMap` is called internally by `Foldable.foldl`, what is the type of the `Monoid`?

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem, thank you for the help. That's exactly what I am confused about, you mentioned `mempty = 1`, then what's the type of the `mempty` here? I cannot quite understand this because unlike `Sum` and `Product`, `Int` is not of typeclass `Monoid` AFAIK. Could you please explain a bit more about this? thanks

Comment: Hmm, I see, I am new to Haskell, I guess that's the part I am missing. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note that this endo trick is pretty advanced, surely not beginner material. Perhaps it's easier to write a `foldl` implementation which first converts any foldable to a plain list, using `foldMap (\x -> [x])` so that the monoid is simply `[a]`, and then doing the `foldl` on the list. It's less efficient, but probably easier to understand. It could make for a good exercise :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit easier to figure out if you consider `foldr`, which has the type `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`. The 'algebra' function has the type `a -> b -> b`, which you can view as `a -> (b -> b)` - that is: a function that takes `a` as input, and returns `b -> b` as output.

Now, `b -> b` is an *endomorphism*, which is also a monoid, and `Data.Monoid` defines a type `Endo a` (or here, it ought perhaps to be `Endo b`), which is, indeed, a `Monoid`.

`foldr` simply uses `Endo` internally to call `foldMap`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. f) t) z
```

`foldl` basically just flips the arguments around in order to do the same trick:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl f z t = appEndo (getDual (foldMap (Dual . Endo . flip f) t)) z
```

To be clear, I literally copied these two function implementation from the Haskell source. If you go to the [documentation of Data.Foldable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html), there are various links to view the source. That's what I did.

Comment: I see, I actually found that part of source code, but couldn't understand the role `Endo` played as I am new to Haskell, will read more about that. Thank you so much :)